# Possible to move data of a specific type from an index with multiple types to an index with one type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have upgraded to latest ES6. ES6 no longer support multiple types, which I have currently have in my indicies.

Therefore I would like to copy all the data from the old index of a specific type (mac-assign) to a new index that only has one type: doc.

I have filtered out the old data form my index with multiple types:

```
GET pers-mac-data-prod/_search
{
   “query”: {
       “type” : {
           “value” : “mac-assign”
       }
   }
}
```

And that's the data I would like to add to my fresh index pers-mac-assign-dev (with the type doc)

Someone who knows if this is doable and how? (I've tried elasticdump without success...)

Comment: The Elasticsearch [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_migrating_multi_type_indices_to_single_type) can copy data from a multiple mapping type index to a single mapping type index.

Comment: @chin-huang Your comment led me to the answer, unfortunately I couldn't vote for it since it's in a comment...see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it possible with the Elasticsearch Reindex API (thanks to the suggestion by Chin Huang in the comments):

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "pers-mac-data-prod",
    "type": "mac-assign"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "pers-mac-assign-dev",
    "type": "doc"
  }
}
```

NB! You have to specify the type for dest as well. You might think it's implicit since new ES6 only handles one type per index but if you omit the dest type it will result in error because it will try to consider the mappings from source with multiple types.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with logstash, using the [elasticsearch input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html)
Basically logstash will search all the events matching your query (filter by type in your case) on the old instance, and in your logstash configuration you then define an elasticsearch output to your new instance.

Do read the link, in its example it indicates the sort by _doc which should be present in your query to reduce the load on your old instance (you do not care about the order of processing of the events as you want all the ones matching your query)